# Site slows down after I load a 50mb JSON data file

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, performance, indexeddb

I have a requirement where I need to load a 50mb JSON file to filter it in the browser. I'm not displaying it all, but rather the file is being loaded (in-memory) inside of the browser for me to perform some search queries.

That being said, the entire site slows down after loading the file—not even trying to search it.

What are some techniques to work with large file in the browser without making HTTP requests for a server to handle the load? That is, I'd like to be able to simply load up the `index.html` file and be able to read the local `JSON` data (50+MB) and perform queries on it.

Here's an example of something I'm wanting to build with instead with 50MB of data: https://rawgit.com/farzher/fuzzysort/master/test.html

In the example above, the static data is provided to `index.html` and I could either load this file with an AJAX request or bundle it as a dependency within the JavaScript file. Just trying to see what options are out there...

Comment: I don't get it? The client send a request to server for `index.html` page, the server loads a `50MB` file .... then ?! We can help if you describe the `sequence` of `request` and `response`. And exactly specify if `server` slow downs or `client` and if you send the `50MB` file to client

Comment: Updated my questions, @AlirezaFattahi. Basically, the file is already there, but it seems that the entire browser slows down with a file this large. For example, just typing inside of the input field seems laggy already.

Comment: It seems that browser storage may have some limitations. What is your browser. I suggest test it with different browsers ( close other tabs). Mean while use https://demo.agektmr.com/storage/ and load a some test data with `50MB`  or even more of test data, and see if the browser slows done there too. If it is OK, then may be some problem with the `javascrpt` code in you site.